# Centralizer acting on the homology of a subgroup

Tags: homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $H\subset G$ be a subgroup. Let $E_*G$ be a free (right) $\mathbb ZG$-resolution of the trivial representation $\mathbb Z$. Because $E_*G$ is then also a free $\mathbb ZH$-resolution of the trivial representation, we can compute the homology of $H$ by
$$H_i(H) = H_i(E_*G \otimes_{\mathbb ZH} \mathbb Z).$$
Let $g\in C_G(H)$ commute with all elements of $H$. Then there is a chain complex map automorphism of $E_*G\otimes_{\mathbb ZH} \mathbb Z$ given by
$$ x \otimes 1 \longmapsto xg \otimes 1.$$

Prove that this map induces the identity on $H_i(H)$.

Comment: This is an exercise from some book?

Comment: No, it's a personal question. But I formulated it in such a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the map $x\mapsto xg$ is an endomorphism of the complex of $H$-modules $E_*G$, and it is in fact a lift of the identity of the right $H$-module $\mathbb Z$ to its resolution $E_*G$. It follows that that map of complexes is homotopic to the identity.

Comment: I guess, I would like to emphasis that you get a homotopy not only for $E_*G \to \mathbb Z \to 0$ but also for $E_*G\to 0$ and by functoriality for $E_*G \otimes_G \mathbb Z \to 0$.
Thanks for the help.